# Si la cadena de un TextBox esta vacia, como se almacena esta "cadena vavia" en una variable entera y como puedo validar su contenido - lenguaje c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen dia, como se almacena una cadena vacia " " de un textBox en una variable  Tipo Int, y luego como puedo validar lo que se guardo en esta variable.

lo que quiero es saber como validar un valor null en una variable entera, y quiero saberlo para poder lanzar una alerta de que el campo "TextBox" esta vacio o no se a ingresado nada, ejemplo tengo un campo de texto llamado descripcion, en este campo se debe ingresar un texto para luego almacenar este texto en una variable tipo String, si fuese el caso que no se ingrese nada en el campo de texto entoncesn verifico que la variable tipo string tiene una cadena vacia y lanzo un mensaje de que hace falta ingresar una descripcion:

```
 if (obj.Descripcion == "")
        {
            Mensaje += "Es necesario la Descripcion del Producto\n";
        }
```

Ahora el problema lo tengo con el campo de texto "Stock" que de no ingresar nada en este tendria una cadena vacia la cual debo ingresarla con algun metodo en mi variable tipo Int, "Stock" de tal forma que luego pueda validar de alguna forma que esta variable "Stock" de tipo Int, no contiene nada y poder notificar que hace falta ingresar el Stock en dicho campo

Comment: ¿Quieres guardar una cadena vacía en una variable entera?

Comment: a qué te refieres con "una variable entera". PD: `textBox1.Text = ""`

Comment: poniendole un poco de humor.. variableentera = ""; variableparti = "da";.. no se entiende nada de tu problema.. si por variable entera te referis a un int, y hago magia para saber de que hablas, podrias guardar un null si nulificas el tipo int...

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, quiero que si no se ingresa nada en un TextBox, entonces en la variable de tipo Int, se almacene algun valor, para luego validarlo y lanzar una alerta de campo vacio o algo asi

Comment: @LPZadkiel, una variable de tipo Int, que me guardaria un valor entero de ser ingresado en el TextBox y de no ser asi tanbien que me almacene un entero para porder validarlo y continuar con otra accion

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga, lo que quiero es saber como validar un valor null en una variable entera, y quiero saberlo para poder lanzar una alerta de que el campo "TextBox" esta vacio o no se a ingresado nada, ejemplo tengo un campo de texto llamado descripcion, en este campo se debe ingresar un texto para luego almacenar este texto en una variable tipo String, si fuese el caso que no se ingrese nada en el campo de texto entoncesn verifico que la variable tipo string tiene una cadena vacia y lanzo un mensaje de que hace falta ingresar una descripcion:

Comment: En realidad no, valida primero el contenido del textbox, y despues, si se puede, pasalo a la variable...

Comment: Hola Mas, me parece que estás haciendo trabajo de... más, valga la redundancia, estás postergando una acción, y hacerlo, te lleva a un escenario... rarín,  mejor sería **if( campo.getTexto() == "" ) { mandoMensajeDeCampoVacio(); } else { stock = conviertoTextoEnInt( campo.getTexto() ); }**, de esta forma te ahorras hacer conversiones raras.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que describes se conoce como "[*overkill*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overkill)":

> *Situación de violencia en la que se aplica una fuerza desmesurada para la consecución de los objetivos*

En español nos referimos a ello como "*matar moscas a cañonazos*".

---

Si necesitas validar que un control de texto tenga valor, no es necesario almacenar nada en ninguna variable adicional para después en base a comprobar el valor en esa otra variable saber que el control de texto está vacío.

Puedes comprobar directamente si el campo de [texto es nulo o vacío](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-7.0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Descripcion))
{
    Mensaje += "Es necesario la Descripcion del Producto\n";
}
```

Esa comprobación no funcionará si la cadena es todo espacios; si quieres que una cadena que sea sólo espacios tampoco cuente como válida puedes eliminarlos con [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) antes de hacer la comprobación:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Descripcion.Trim()))
{
    Mensaje += "Es necesario la Descripcion del Producto\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes primero validar si tú cadena viene vacía ya sea con un `txt==" " Or . Txt.length<0` en tu variable entera puedes guardarlo como `0` o `null`.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No puedes guardar `null` en una variable entera.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Para intentar convertir un `string` en un `int` puedes usar `TryParse`

```
if(int.TryParse(unaVariableString, out int result))
{
    //Se pudo convertir el string en int
    //la variable 'result' tiene el int resultante
}
else
{
   //No se pudo convertir el string
}
```

---

2.- Para saber si un string es nulo o vacío usas `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(unaVariableString))
{
    //El string es nulo o vacío
}
else
{
    //el string no es vacío
}
```

---

3.- Para saber si un string es nulo, vacío o contiene espacio usas `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unaVariableString))
{
    //El string es nulo, vacío o contiene solo espacios
}
else
{
    //el string no es vacío
}
```

Se considera como espacio el mismo espacio (evidentemente), el tab y otros caracteres descritos [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-7.0)